# Recent GPU update - Windows 10 crashed while only Spotify was running

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu, crash

2 days ago I changed from a 1050 ti to a 1660 Super. Today morning while I was listening to music on Spotify, my PC froze with that weird crackling sound and I had to switch off the mains to shut it. The card has normal temps, clock speed and other parameters (checked with GPUz, Riva Tuner, Heaven) and it doesn't overheat/crash even while gaming. My case has pretty good cooling (I use the old school CM HAF 922 with 200 mm fans) so I am not sure if it was a heat issue. And I am not sure how only Spotify (and background anti virus, Steam) could cause it to overheat, if it did. How do I diagnose this? Could it be Spotify's 'Hardware Acceleration' causing this?

My specs:

- Ryzen 5 1600
- GTX 1660 Super
- 16 Gigs of DDR 4 RAM
- Mortar B450 Max Mobo
- WD Nvme SSD
- Corsair 650W PSU Gold Rated

Comment: Did you check for driver updates, especially GPU and mainboard?

Comment: I installed the relevant driver for the new GPU, but not for the mainboard; do I need to? The last time I switched from an AMD card to NVidia, didn't have to install anything for the mobo specifically. What exactly do I look for?